# Phrase "sporting person", correct usage

Tags: phrase-usage

Is "Sporting person" the correct phrase to refer to someone who love/do sport, regularly perform athletics or play sports and games?

Comment: "sportsperson" or "athlete" is the appropriate term to describe such a person.

Comment: *Athlete* is the most common word for this.

Comment: @MamtaD: Put that in an answer?

Comment: worth noting - *'sporting gents and ladies'* would mean it all different!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"Sportsperson"** or **"athlete"** is the appropriate term to describe such a person.

**Sporting** when used in reference to a person means *fair and generous in one's behaviour or treatment of others, especially in a contest*.